# CodePipeline: How to integrate ECR with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-ecr

I'm trying to combine ECR and Elastic Beanstalk with the following CodePipeline setup:

1. Source : CodeCommit
2. Build : `buildspec.yml` which Builds a docker image and pushes it to ECR repository
3. Deploy: Elastic Beanstalk

Note that Step 2 doesn't contain any artifacts, it merely builds the new image from the source code by using `docker build -t <my-image> .` and pushes it to ECR with the latest tag.

My Questions are:

1. How do you trigger beanstalk from step 3 to use the latest ECR image?

   1. Which artifacts should be included (if any) from step 1/2?
   2. Is the artifact is just the same `Dockerrun.aws.json` which point to the ECR image file every time?
2. Alternative way: Should I just deploy the entire source code to beanstalk and let it use the Dockerfile in the package instead so it will build it?

   1. if so - Where can I see the build process of the image?
   2. Is there a way to select a different Dockerfile from the source code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer: include only the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file in artifacts of `buildspec.yml` and point it's `image` field to the ECR image.